# Binding a view with model is showing error in namespace in mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having a problem passing to the View a Model that contains few properties. With this code i am getting error

> The type name Entity does not exist in the type'viewmodel namespace

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult Index()
   {
       return View(GetProducts());
   }
private static IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> GetProducts()
   {
       var northwind = new NorthwindDataContext();
       return northwind.Products.Select(product => new ProductViewModel
       {
           ProductID = product.ProductID,
           ProductName = product.ProductName,
           UnitPrice = product.UnitPrice ?? 0,
           UnitsInStock = product.UnitsInStock ?? 0,
           UnitsOnOrder = product.UnitsOnOrder ?? 0,
           Discontinued = product.Discontinued,
           LastSupply = DateTime.Today
       });
   }
```

**VIEWMODEL**

```
namespace AutoComplete.Entity
{
 public class ProductViewModel
 {
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int ProductID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Product name")]
    public string ProductName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Unit price")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Range(0, int.MaxValue)]
    public decimal UnitPrice
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Units in stock")]
    [DataType("Integer")]
    [Range(0, int.MaxValue)]
    public int UnitsInStock
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool Discontinued
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DisplayName("Last supply")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime LastSupply
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public short UnitsOnOrder { get; set; }
}
}
```

**VIEW**

```
@model IEnumerable<AutoComplete.Entity.ProductViewModel>
```

Comment: Is this the complete description of the error? `The type name Entity does not exist in the type'viewmodel namespace'`

Comment: Make sure ProductViewModel.cs is included in the project.